# upgrading to new board worth it (keeping old cpu) ? From SATA2/DDR2 to SATA3/DDR3

Tags: ssd, cpu, motherboard

I currently own a AMD Phenom II X4 955 with a AM3 board (with SATA2 only and DDR2).  I recently bought a Samsung 850 EVO ssd drive (250GB) for the OS.

I know I'm not using my SATA3 SSD drive to it's full capacity.  I could buy a PCIe SATA3 controller card for like $25.  I heard some of them are not working very well.

I was thinking of upgrading to a new AM3+ board for like $100.  I would then also buy DDR3 memory which is reasonably cheap these days.

Question is: Would the combination of SATA3 and DDR3 over SATA2 and DDR2 be worth it ?  Would I see a significant (or at least decent) difference ?

Comment: Worth it or not? -> Opinion based answers.

Comment: Also, the expected speed gain from HDD to SSD on SATA-II to SSD on SATA-III is imho probably not worth it.  Take this imaginary task: HDD: 60 seconds.  SSD: 7 seconds.  SSD on SATA-III: 6 seconds. Law of deminishing returns.

Answer (score 0):

From My own experience I can tell you that difference in moving from SATA2 to SATA3 with 850 Evo is not noticeable, except for benchmarks.

However, moving from ddr2 to ddr3 IS noticeable. First the difference feels your wallet, as ddr2 is getting obsolete and harder to get bigger sticks. Second, the performance increases noticeably as well, but, OTOH, it's not dramatic. So depending on amount of ram in your system and your plans regarding adding more moving to new board may be a good idea. Especially if you use onboard VGA chip (if they work off system RAM), so switching to DDR3 will improve things here as well.